# Search Controller for words

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uisearchcontroller

I have followed below example code for search feature in my application
https://www.raywenderlich.com/157864/uisearchcontroller-tutorial-getting-started

Everything is working fine and searching is also working perfectly. but when I enter the words in different order/sequence it does not give me the results. below is the example of what I want

```
var String = "High, Fever"
var String = "fever"
```

Now when I search like "fever" it gives me the both in response but When I search something like "fever h" it does not give me the string.. in my case they just enter the words regardlessly their sequence..

Below is my code

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "Present") {
        filteredsymptoms = symptoms.filter({( symptoms : Symptoms) -> Bool in
            let doesCategoryMatch = (scope == "Present") || (scope == "Absent") || (scope == "Focus")

            if searchBarIsEmpty() {
                return doesCategoryMatch
            } else {
                return doesCategoryMatch && symptoms.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
            }
        })
        print(filteredsymptoms)
        self.tblListOfSymptoms.reloadData()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
symptoms.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()
```

This part of code will check if "symptoms.name" contains whole search text, "fever h" in your case.
If you want to search all parts of text which separated by spaces, you should use something like this:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "Present") {
    filteredsymptoms = symptoms.filter({( symptoms : Symptoms) -> Bool in
        let doesCategoryMatch = (scope == "Present") || (scope == "Absent") || (scope == "Focus")

        if searchBarIsEmpty() {
            return doesCategoryMatch
        } else {
            var result:Bool = false
            let searchTerms = searchText.lowercased().components(separatedBy: CharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines)
            for searchTerm in searchTerms
            {
                result = doesCategoryMatch && symptoms.name.lowercased().contains(searchTerm)
                if result == true
                {
                    break
                }
            }
            return result
        }
    })
    print(filteredsymptoms)
    self.tblListOfSymptoms.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on the result that you want to achieve. If you want the user to type multiple words and search for any of those use following code:

```
searchText.lowercased().components(separatedBy: " ").map({ symptoms.name.lowercased().contains($0) }).reduce(false, { $0 || $1 })
```